# Find PID of created PHP process in PHP

Tags: php, pid

I first execute the following command,

```
 $retVal = proc_close(proc_open("rfcomm connect \/dev\/rfcomm0 &> /dev/null 2> /dev/null &", array(), $pipe));
```

I have to use proc_close right after proc_open or the command hangs my php page. Later on my script if I try to find out the PID of this background process I only get returned my grep request:

```
$val = shell_exec("ps aux | grep rfcomm0");
```

It only returns the process of my grep command:

> www-data 6412 0.0 0.3 2004 624 ? S 12:23 0:00 grep rfcomm0

Now if I enter the exact same command from shell_exec into my SSH terminal on my server I get the following:

```
www-data  6047  0.0  0.3   1752   592 ?        S    12:10   0:00 rfcomm connect /dev/rfcomm0 
root      6415  0.0  0.4   3532   804 pts/1    S+   12:27   0:00 grep rfcomm0
```

The first result is the PID I want. Is PHP unable to retrieve the PID of its own processes or is there another way to solve this mystery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get PID using proc_get_status ...

http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-get-status.php

This function returns an array which one of it's element's are pid. It's input parameter is return of proc_open ...

Comment: Just also found out, but the pid difference by one. For example the function returns 6622 but the actual PID (if I look at ps aux) is 6623. Strange right?

Comment: There are lot's of bug reports about wrong PID by proc_get_status, maybe a php version upgrade can fix this?

Comment: I've just added +1 at the end, after 10 times it always returns the same error. Thanks!

Comment: By same error you mean same wrong PID or a specific error message? If you have a specific error message, post it, it may help.

Comment: Same wrong PID, I've read on php.net manual that this is a know bug and not yet fixed, +1 is not 100% save but does the job :)

Answer (score 0):

By usgin `proc_get_status()`, you could get the `proc_open` process ID from `pid` value, and get the opened command process ID which is the next number of parent PID (parent PID + 1):

```
$desc = [
    ["pipe","r"],
    ["pipe","w"],
    ["pipe","w"],
    ];

$p = proc_open('php ./process.php', $desc, $pipes);
$s = proc_get_status($p);

$parentPID = $s['pid'];      // proc_open itself
$processPID = $s['pid'] + 1; // 'php ./process.php'

proc_close($p);
```